# firbird UPDATE or INSERT without changing unique ID

Tags: php, insert, firebird

I have this query in PHP

```
$id = ibase_gen_id(TABLE1_ID_GEN);
$query = "UPDATE OR INSERT INTO TABLE1(ID, TESTER_ID, LOT_ID, TEST_STEP) VALUES (.....)
              MATCHING (TESTER_ID, LOT_ID, TEST_STEP)";

$processQuery = ibase_query($query);
```

this query works but when updating the record, the ID also updated. I want to update the record (TESTER_ID, LOT_ID, and TEST_STEP) without updating/changing its ID.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't specify the ID in your query then?

Comment: that ID is incrementing. Do I need to remove ID in the query?

Comment: how about showing the actual query used

Comment: If you don't want to update the record with a new ID, then you need to remove the ID field from the list of values that you're writing into the record. Pretty straightforward, no? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I got it! I removed the ID and it works fine. Thanks!!

Comment: Another option would be to use [`MERGE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-merge.html) instead. The syntax is a bit more complex, but it allows for more complex scenarios.